# jQuery validate add class to error element?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have the following code using jQuery Validate.

```
$("#register").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorClass:'error',
    validClass:'success',
    errorElement:'span',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
        $(element).parents("div.control-group")
                  .addClass(errorClass)
                  .removeClass(validClass);
    }, 
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents(".error")
                  .removeClass(errorClass)
                  .addClass(validClass); 
    }
});
```

Is there a way to add a class to the errorElement, 'span' so that it's...:

```
<span class="help-inline error">Message</span>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you specify the `errorClass`, there's nothing stopping you from making it two things:  "help-inline error", i.e.:

```
$("#register").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorClass: 'error help-inline',
    validClass: 'success',
    errorElement: 'span',
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    }
});
```

Note that you have to use version 1.10 of jQuery Validate to support this.  Earlier versions only allow one `errorClass`.

Comment: I tried this but then I'm getting this weird thing where a span is getting added (but not removed on the highlight)...

Comment: Ah you're right, the github version actually fixes this - check out the `errors` function here:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L492  Replace your version of jquery Validate with that, or just that one function ought to be enough...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative of Ryley answer that not include the 'help-inline' into 'control-group' that avoid input offset on highlight.

```
$("#register").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorClass: 'error help-inline',
    validClass: 'success',
    errorElement: 'span',
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass('error').removeClass('success');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).parents(".error").removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

I cound't to include that issue like a comment of the answer...;o(,.

Answer (score 0):

Because I think this is for Twitter Booststrap, this is a better solution with no need to update jquery validation:

```
$("#register").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorClass: 'help-inline',
    validClass: 'success',
    errorElement: 'span',
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass("error");

    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).parents(".error").removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".error").addClass('help-inline')
```

will add the `help-inline` class to all DOM elements with the `error` class already.

Is that what you are looking for?